# How to assign role to EC2 instance started as part of Auto-Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, autoscaling

I have my EC2 instance with a role assigned to it. This EC2 instance is part of Auto-scaling-group. How do I make sure that new EC2 instances spawned as part of ASG also has same IAM role as current EC2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a [Launch Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html) for the ASG. Luckily, AWS supports creating an [Launch Configuration from an existing EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-lc-with-instanceID.html), which you can use to create a launch configuration based on what you need.

Comment: that i am aware of creating ASG etc.. But will this make sure that Role is automatically assigned to any new EC2 instance ?  because even that link does NOT talk about inheriting role .

Comment: Auto Scaling launches instances based on the configuration specified in the Launch Configuration.  i.e. anything defined in the LC will be applied to newly launched instances.  @Blokje5's answer is correct. Read more about LC at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

Anything you are specified in the launch-configuration(AMI - ec2) that will applied to all the EC2 instances which are launching through auto-scale group.